# Php check in dir if user picture exists

Tags: php, file, file-exists

I am trying to do the following

```
<?php 

echo '<img  style="margin-top:10px;" src="images/'.$_SESSION['username'].'.png" width="200px;" height="200px;">'; 

?>
```

But I need to check if the image exists and then if exist I echo the username session image else I echo another picture with a face

Comment: Looks like you'd like to call a function Instead of a global variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Session check not working when i redirect from another page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28743651/php-session-check-not-working-when-i-redirect-from-another-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i solved it

```
    <?php 


    $rootPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $thisPath = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $onlyPath = str_replace($rootPath, '', $thisPath);
    $extension = ".png";
    $all =  $onlyPath.$_SESSION['username'].$extension;

if (file_exists($all)){

    echo '<img  style="margin-top:10px;" src="'.$onlyPath.$_SESSION['username'].'.png" width="200px;" height="200px;">';

} else {
  echo '<img  style="margin-top:10px;" src="usericon.png" width="200px;" height="200px;">';
}

    ?>
```

Other ways how to solve it

```
<?php 

$user = $_SESSION ["username"];
$dir = 'images/'.$user.'.png';

if (file_exists($dir)) {
    //exists
} else {
   //not exists
}

?>
```